# If a man divorces his wife, does his daughter become halal for him to marry?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, children

If a man has a daughter with a woman and then many years later, he divorces the woman, does his daughter become halal for him to marry?

Comment: No she doesn't, the daughter remains his daughter even though he divorced the mother. Mahrams established by blood relations do not ever become non-mahrams.

Answer (score 2):

It's forbidden; the Qur'an is clear on this:

> Prohibited to you [for marriage] are ... your daughters ... and your step-daughters under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto whom you have gone in. -- [Qur'an 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23)

She remains his daughter after divorce, and the father retains his rights and responsibilities as a father ("at all times, the father of the child is responsible for maintaining the child" -- [Mufti Muhammad ibn Adam](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/5385)).

The Qur'an even goes further to forbid marrying step-daughters (see above).

Comment: and what if the man divorces the mother of the step-daughter? she is no longer his step-daughter

Comment: @JimKite A step daughter remains a permanent mahram, unless the divorce was given before the marriage was consummated.  From 4:23 "... and your step-daughters under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto whom you have gone in. But if you have not gone in unto them, there is no sin upon you."